# Set blogue page as the default page in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, wordpress

I am using Magento WordPress Integration (Fishpig).

I am trying to set the Default page of Magento as the main blog page.

Right now I have to force a redirect.

So how can I have the main page of Magento as the blog without a redirect?

Comment: Try this extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-wordpress-integration.html

Comment: @Su123 the author literally says in the first sentence that they're already using this integration.

Comment: Oops, sorry my mistake, I didn't notice it. Thanks for figuring out :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support.